# Sprite not rotating when I have an if statement

Tags: sprite-kit

I'm using spritekit in xcode to make my first little game. I'm a complete beginner right now with programming, so I'm having a little bit of trouble.

I'm trying to rotate this board (a rectangle) when I swipe to the left of right. I only want the board to rotate when it's at a certain x and y position.

So here is the code that DOES work:

```
func swipedLeft() {

  board.run(rotateActionLeft)
  board.run(goLeft)
  board.run(goUp)

}
```

So what this basically does is rotate my board -90 degrees and makes it go up to the left. When I swipe to the left it works.

If I put an if statement in the function like this:

```
  func swipedLeft() {

if position.board.y == -600{

board.run(rotateActionLeft)
board.run(goLeft)
board.run(goUp)

}

}
```

Nothing happens. When I try to swipe to the left, the board doesn't go anywhere. When I go to the game scene in xcode, the board's inital position is at y is -600.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: `position.board.y == -600` must be returning false. Have you checked that? I don't know Swift, so I don't know if there's a more proper way to check integer equality, but I'd have to challenge your assertion that the y position is in fact -600.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/f9674144b3907db2ed99d3dad1cafb70

Comment: hey there, did my answer help you? If not, let me know so I can try to update it for you.

Comment: The starting y position was actually something like -599.9895... I found this out using print. So I used that long decimal with my if statement and it still didn't work. So I just tried something like this: if board.position.y < -599   it would work out. Still don't know why the decimal did not work and why spritekit doesn't set it to exactly -600 . Thanks for the help, though.

Answer (score 0):

what is `positon.board.y`? This is not the proper `CGPoint` syntax, which tells me you are using a subclass?

So, this means that either:

1. Your sprite has moved since being created in the SKSeditor. the sks editor will not always be accurate. you should add  a `print` statement above the `if` statement to see what it is :)
2. Your custom position.board thingy isn't functioning properly. Try using the actual `SKNode().position.y` and see if that fixes it.